# Where to put Python files to be redirected to by urls.py in Django?

Tags: python, django, frameworks, django-urls

Where do I put python files to be redirected to by urls.py in Django? The tutorial showed something like this:

> urlpatterns = patterns('',
>       (r'^polls/$', '**mysite.polls.views.index**'),

Where do I set up pages to be easily linked as something.something.page like this? I am currently just trying to drop straight .py files in random directories and typing the name of the file in the urls.py file like so:

> urlpatterns = patterns('',
>       (r'file', '**file.py**'),

Which is obviously not the correct way to do it. How do I create pages to be linked to in urls.py? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use views. You can create views (keep reading the official django documentation), then import them into your urls.py file and use them. Here's an example:

### views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

def index(request):
   """
   Main page.
   """
   return render_to_response('index.html') # display index.html
```

### urls.py

```
from myproject.views import index
urlpatterns = patterns('',
   (r'^$', index),
)
```

This example will display your index.html page whenever you visit the root of your website (eg: /).